# Robocopy backup- / restartmodus (/Z) doesn't work

Tags: windows, robocopy

I have problems with the restart-modus /resume of Robocopy. I use it with the "/Z" or "/ZB" switches and if my drive gets disconnected or I stop Robocopy with STRG+C the file(s) will not be resumed and the transfer starts at 0% next time.

I could reproduce it very clearly, because :

1. I copied a video file to ~80%
2. I was able to watch the file till 80% of the movie (surprise :-) )
3. started Robocopy again (it even shows in the log that it starts at 1%), stopped after some seconds and 
   the video file was only watchable at the beginning. Same with other files.

I copied from a USB 3.0 drive to an internal hard-drive.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure how restartable exactly works but I can imagine it restarting from the beginning if the algorithm notices any file attribute of your 80% copy has changed. Perhaps your viewer changed it. You can verify this too very clearly by following your steps but leave out step 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it:

**/Z only works if you transfer data from a network device**. I copied from hard drive to hard drive (SATA to external USB 3.0), so there it didn't resume files.

Would be nice if the help file would be updated or describe the switches more, it's really kind of lacking information.

So if you use /Z on a transfer over a network it resumes, but it's REALLY slower, I guess it's only worth/necessary if you have really big files and/or many disconnects.